# Recursion, reverse string

Tags: python, string, recursion

```
def swap(aList):

 swap(aList):

  if len(aList) == 0:
      return 0
  elif len(aList) == 1:
      print(aList[0])
      return aList[0]
  return aList[0] + swap(aList[2:])

aList = [["abcdefgh"]]

swap(aList)
```

The code above prints, but it prints the aList in order, from a-h. LIKE SO: "abcdefgh"

I need to print every two letters in reverse; LIKE SO: "badcfehg".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As a start - you're not actually *swapping* anything.

Comment: @zach_93, please don't ask the same question twice.